# Cygwin g++ x86_64 segmentation fault (core dumped) when using > 2GB memory

Tags: c++, memory, g++, segmentation-fault, cygwin

I've written a prime sieve program in c++, which uses ~12GB ram to calculate all primes below 100,000,000,000 (100 Billion).

The program works fine when compiled with Visual Studio 2012 (in a project set up for x64) as well as g++ on 64 bit linux. However, when compiled with g++ in cygwin64 on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, a segmentation fault occurs when attempting to use more than ~2GB ram (running the sieve for > ~17,000,000,000)

I'm fairly sure it's running as a 64 bit process as there's no *32 next to the process name in task manager.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

long long sieve(long long n);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const long long ONE_BILLION = 1000*1000*1000;
    if(argc == 2)
        cout << sieve(atol(argv[1])) << endl;
    else
        cout << sieve(ONE_BILLION * 100) << endl;
}

long long sieve(long long n) {
    vector<bool> bools(n+1);
    for(long long i = 0; i <=n; i++) 
        bools[i] = true;

    double csqrtn = sqrt(n);
    for (long long i = 2; i < csqrtn; ++i)
        if (bools[i]) 
            for (long long j = i * i; j < n; j += i) 
                bools[j] = false;

    long long primes2 = 0;
    for (long long i = 2; i < n; i++) 
        if (bools[i]) 
            primes2++;

    return primes2;
}
```

Working fine in Visual studio:

[image]

Working fine on x64 linux:

[image]

Compiled with the command:

`$ g++ -O3 sieve.cpp -o sieve.exe`

Running for 18 billion fails:

```
$ ./sieve.exe 18000000000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Works fine (using 2,079,968 K memory according to task manager, though my reputation doesn't allow me to post a third link.)

```
$ ./sieve.exe 17000000000
755305935
```

g++ version:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Note: if you are going to try and run this yourself, it can take quite a long time. On a 3570k @ 4.2GHz running 100 billion in visual studio takes around 30 mins, 1 billion around 10 seconds. However you might be able to duplicate the error with just the vector allocation.

Edit: since I didn't explicitly put a question: Why does this happen? Is it a limitation of the cygwin64 dll (cygwin64 was only released fully about a month ago)?

Comment: Are you able to catch the segfault with gdb? Perhaps the backtrace might suggest the source of the problem.

Comment: I've never used gdb before but here's the output (compiled without optimizations): http://pastebin.com/gUANvzpx The addresses listed are 64 bit, though 0xffffffffdc3cba00 looks very high (10^19)

Comment: Did you compile with -g to get debug symbols? The pastbin backtrace didn't have any debug symbols from your program. See http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/gdb.html

Comment: Try another gcc build such as mingw.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the cygwin memory limit. This [cygwin documentation](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-maxmem.html) suggests that the default maximum application heap size on 64-bit platforms is 4GB... although, this may be referring to 32-bit executables on 64-bit platforms... not sure what restrictions cygwin64 64-bit applications would have regarding their maximum heap size.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference, I set it to 13gb (a little under my amount of free memory) and 18 billion still gave the segfault. About compiling with -g from your comment, the output from backtrace was no different. I'll asssume this is some sort of bug in cygwin64 and take it to their mailing list.